# Windows 11 installation does not find NVMe drive

Tags: windows-installation, windows-11-v22h2

I have a desktop computer with an AMD Ryzen 4650 PRO CPU on an ASUS Prime B550-A mainboard with an Samsung Evo 980 NVMe SSD. The system works flawlessly with Linux, but now I need to install Windows 11 on the machine.

I got the installation medium from Microsoft (Windows 11 22h2 64 bit ISO) and created a bootable USB device using the following methods:

- Ventoy 1.0.88
- Gnome-multi-writer
- WoeUSB 5.2.4

I copied the ISO on different USB sticks and tried to install Windows. Nothing worked, mainly because Windows does not recognize the disk, so it has no drive to install it to.

In the UEFI I configured:

- TPM 2.0 enabled
- using the firmware fTPM module
- booting as "other OS" (no Secure Boot).

NVMe is correctly recognized in the UEFI (obviously, as it boots perfectly fine into Linux).

I tried

- Ventoy normal installation: I get an error saying boot configuration
  missing or contains errors

[image: screenshot]

- Ventoy WIMBOOT installation: starts but does not recognize the NVMe
- Gnome-multi-writer image: starts but does not recognize the NVMe
- WoeUSB: starts but does not recognize the NVMe

I switched to Secure Boot, but the I get a Secure Boot violation for Ventoy and for the other two versions, the PC just keeps on booting the UEFI without loading the image.

When I enable NVMe raid, the disk is no longer recognized by the UEFI.

I tried to find drivers, but neither AMD nor ASUS have drivers. The only help I found was for Intel chipsets, but nothing for AMD.

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: I use Samsung NVMe drives on 3 machines and WIndows 11 Pro. Works fine. Try an ordinary Windows - only install. Make a Windows 11 Installer on USB with the Media Creation Link or the Windows Installer Media.    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d   ....  Works great and includes SSDs ..   Make sure (WhyNotWin11) that your computer has everything for Windows 11

Comment: The method shouldn't make any difference for this particular problem.  *How* the drive is partitioned certainly does > Windows 11 does NOT  support Legacy ("BIOS") mode or MBR. It strictly requires UEFI mode with Secure Boot enabled and a GPT drive as a target. Please check ALL of the requirements and then [edit] your question accordingly to update it.

Comment: WhyNotWin11 (GitHub) will expose weaknesses or no-go in your setup

Comment: Why are we talking about Legacy Boot? The Windows installation is clearly not configured to boot in CSM otherwise it wouldn’t complain about the EFI partition. It’s the BCD configuration, as evident, by the BCD error.

Comment: I tried both, legacy boot and secure boot. Both failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the comments. The solution was as easy as annoying. For some reason the USB boot media created from linux using the 3 mentioned ways above leads to messed up USB sticks. All variants (legacy and secure boot, CSM on and off) lead to either the disk not recognized or the installer didn't start at all.

Solution: I organized a windows laptop, used the same ISO file and just transferred it to the same USB stick using Rufus and the installation worked perfectly. I'm not sure if my Ubuntu is messed up and creates faulty USB sticks, or if there is a different problem. All I can say is that I was unable to create a working windows boot medium using a linux/Ubuntu 22.10 system.

TL;DR: use windows when creating a windows boot USB, then it works.